# altering the right hand gap in a menu - css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a NEW indicator on a menu item within WordPress

I am using the following code

`<span class='new-badge-1'>NEW</span>`

my CSS is

```
.new-badge-1 {
    position: relative;
    background: #c32545;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 3px 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    left: -11px;
}
  
.new-badge-1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #c32545;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
}
```

Which works fine.

However there is a noticeable gap between the 'new' icon when displayed on the page and the next menu item.

How can I reduce this gap to the right?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
position: absolute;
```

for

```
.new-badge-1
```

Or set a negative margin-right which should be equal to the width of the badge.

Comment: Thanks, sadly didn't work  - the 'new' was on the line below as opposed to say  'Planning & More' moved closer to it to reduce the gap

Comment: Can you please share a test case, so i can see why it did not work? (or at least the full html?)